# Adding Text Annotation AFTER uploading a YouTube Video

Tags: youtube, youtube-studio

I misspoke in the middle of a video I uploaded to YouTube and I'd like to insert a text annotation into the video (at that point) to clarify the error.

I've already posted the video-link to a forum for the parties who will be watching it, so I'd like to achieve this annotation without invalidating that link (which is what would happen if I removed the video, added the annotation offline, and re-uploaded it.)

Is it possible, **using the editor provided by YouTube**, to insert a text annotation at any arbitrary point?

The tutorials I've found, regarding this task, are outdated and no longer work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Annotations editor have been removed from YouTube. You can no longer add text annotations, only cards and end screens.